# how to get rid of ".0" in python

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have the dataframe `df.info()`:

```
M   5899 non-null float64
```

I need to get rid of the `.0` that the column M has.

`df['M'].value_counts()`

```
4354.0     4382
454.0        98
234324.0     98
```

I have tried `df['M'].astype('int64')` which gives me the same results as above.

What can I do to get rid of the decimal zero?

Comment: Did you assign `df['M'] = df['M'].astype('int64')` before running `df['M'].value_counts()`?

Comment: yes, actually the df['M'].value_counts() should be the last entry..

Comment: why would you want to *get rid* of the decimal place? Note that you have floating point numbers; so it's a matter of display

Comment: I need the numbers as integers no float

Comment: There is no doubting that `df['M'] = df['M'].astype('int64')` will convert the column to **int** values. Are you sure you assign the converted column back to the column using `df['M']=`?

Comment: you are right, I forgot to saved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change option pandas for display if you don't want to change type of the column

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'M': [5899.0, 4354.0, 454.0, 234324.0],
}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

pd.set_option('display.precision', 0)
df['M'].value_counts()
```